# Captured photo scanning android

Tags: android, android-camera, photo, qr-code

How is it possible to scan the photo that was captured by camera and get text or numbers which were captured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read up on OCR: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition

Find a library that works on android and integrate it into your project.